# iOS/iPad orientation change: rotate views manually vs. have 1 view ready for each orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, orientation-changes

I have been debating with my boss **which of the following is a better way of accounting for an iPad device orientation changes**:

1. Rotating / resizing all views as necessary / making sure their autoresizingmasks are set correctly
2. In IB, having 2 views pre-made: 1 as the portrait view, and 1 as the landscape view, and, for each orientation change, saying self.view = **_** (based on which direction we land on).

Not sure which is better. I just feel like option (1) uses less memory than (2), but can be slightly more tedious?

**Any ideas / other pros or cons for either approach?** Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should use both:

1. Use autoresizingmasks  when the content of the view is the same and all you need to do is make sure that the content is properly re sized and properly positioned, for this definitely you can use autoresizemasks or springs and struts in xib files
2. Use 2 different xib files when your content is not the same(extra/less views and the view positioning is really different) for landscape and portrait.

Comment: what if I am using storyboards and don't ever use actual .xib files?

Comment: You can create view controllers for landscape and portrait in the same storyboard but you will have to check the orientation before performing a segue between a view controller and another view controller that can be in landscape and portrait.